# Tmpfs with overflow on disk?

Tags: linux, tmpfs, ramdisk

I'm looking for a way to have a tmpfs-like file system that can be unlimited in size, but will use a specified amount of RAM after which the "oversize" data will be stored on another disk-backed filesystem

[image: tmpfs]

I'm running on a SSD-only system, with low available space (usually < 3 GB), so I don't want to reserve any space for SWAP or similar (that's my main requirement)

Do you know of any solution that would fit my use-case ?

Comment: The functionality you desire is already the default behaviour. Linux automatically caches files in RAM for you. Maybe you should describe your use case in more detail.

Comment: If Linux already does this then why do some distros use the tmpfs file system for `/tmp/`? I'm assuming Linux's default cache behavior is designed for persistent files and won't handle this use case that well

Comment: @HeathMitchell tmpfs is used to help *writes*: no reason to waste SSD wear (or tie up HDD writing) on a temporary file. It also probably makes it likely to stay in RAM for longer (although it still *could* get swapped to disk).

Comment: As far as a use-case: I have 32GB of RAM, most of which is unused most of the time. I can not max out my download speed when writing to my SSD. I *can*, and would like to, max out my download speed when writing to RAM. (This would also avoid unnecessary wear and trims.) However, not all files will be <32GB, and I won't always have enough RAM available either. (In either case, the file must be copied to HDD after being downloaded - usually also extracted etc - so the fact that a tmpfs has no persistence has only upsides). But, since when does SO require a use case? The question is clear.

Comment: In my humble opinion, you want a disk backed filesystem with well tuned caching.

Comment: @HeathMitchell The problem is deeper. The filesystems are good, but they have totally braindamaged cache syncs. For example, ext4 does a sync in every 5 seconds, do you want it or not!!! You can turn it off, but who knows it? Another problem, also a lot of software is doing full unneeded syncs, for example firefox or postgresql. That is lesser easy to handle, but wrapping the sync-like syscalls does what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any filesystem that matches your request. FWIW, decades ago, back when memory was more scarce, I recall that some Unix variants had a tmpfs filesystem that used spinning disk space but prioritized speed over recoverability.

You can get closer to what you're looking for in one of two ways.   First, use a `tmpfs` filesystem and replace your overflow area with equivalent extra swap space. Note that swap space doesn't have to be provided by a partition.

The other half measure would be to use `ext4` or another filesystem and set tunables such as `min_batch_time` and `max_batch_time` to outrageous values.